# What happens if a JavaScript variable is re-initialized?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm not sure if there is anything called re-initialization in javascript, so please excuse if there is no such concept.

What happens if a javascript variable is re-initialized?
Ex:

```
function foo()
{
var x = 10;
.... //do something
.... //do something
.... //do something
var x = 20;
console.log("x: " + x);
}
```

What would be the value of x here?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just test it?

Comment: The variable will be 20. However, if you're using strict mode, as you should, the above will give you an error.

Comment: You can try this yourself before posting. 2 mins of google will give your answer.

Comment: @Nit: No, strict mode doesn't make duplicate `var`s an error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right you are, linting in strict mode will give you an error for it though.

Comment: @Nit: I would expect any decent linter to give you a message about it regardless of strict/loose mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` will be 20. `var` is "hoisted" (more below), which means that the variable gets declared as of the beginning of the function, before any step-by-step code is run. Any initializer on a `var` statement is actually just an assignment statement.

So your code:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 10;
    //do something
    var x = 20;
    console.log("x: " + x);
}
```

is treated as though it were like this:

```
function foo() {
    var x;

    x = 10;
    //do something
    x = 20;
    console.log("x: " + x);
}
```

When you call a function, the JavaScript engine does several things *before* it starts executing the step-by-step code in the question. one of the things it does is look through the code and process any `var` statements. (Although it's called the `var` statement, `var` is more of a *declaration*.)

It's quite fun, your code could also be written this way:

```
function foo() {
    x = 10;
    //do something
    x = 20;
    console.log("x: " + x);

    return;

    var x;
}
```

It would still be valid, and it would do exactly the same thing.

More (on my blog): [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

ES6 will introduce `let`, which behaves differently (amongst other things, it is scoped to the block it's in, whereas `var` is scoped to the function as a whole even if declared within a block); [details on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Answer (score 0):

The `var` keyword essentially just determines the scope of the variable and is handled before any of the code is actually executed (look up "hoisting"). Using `var` twice for the variable is redundant, but doesn't really do anything in particular. In the end you're just assigning `10` to `x` and later you assign `20` to `x`; nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score -1):

You can always run simple test to check that. `var` means it's this variable is in current scope. So in your example `x` will be equal to 20

```js
var x = 10;
var x = 20;
var y = 10;

function Test() {
  var x = 30;
  y = 20;
  alert('X in function: ' + x);
  alert('Y is global, so it\'s ' + y);
}

Test();
alert('X outside of function: ' + x + ', also Y = ' + y);
```